# Druid SQL vs Druid Native Query

Tags: druid

I have some question about Druid Query.

According to official document, there are two query language which are Druid query and Native query.

In my use, I feel more comfortable to use Druid Sql because I don't know about Native Query well and have a simple code.

But, I don't know the difference in performance between two query languages.

Is there a large difference in performance between them?

I saw a [druid forum writing in 2019.07](https://www.druidforum.org/t/druid-sql-vs-druid-native-queries/4835). In that document, Recommand using Druid SQL in Druid 0.15.0 or after. (for now, latest Druid version is 0.23.0)

Which are better to use Druid Query or Native Query??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But, I don't know the difference in performance between two query
> languages.
>
> Is there a large difference in performance between them?

Every Druid SQL query gets translated into a native query. According to the [docs](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/sql-translation.html), there's a slight overhead in translating the query from SQL to native, but that's

> the only minor performance penalty to using Druid SQL compared to
> native queries.

To specifically answer your question of

> Which are better to use Druid Query or Native Query??

continue using what you are comfortable with.

If you'd like to learn more about best practices and native queries, the linked doc goes into quite a bit of detail.